# TS2307: Cannot find module with correct path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import

I'm trying to import a file into my react project but am running into this error: "TS2307: Cannot find module ./img/image1.jpg or its corresponding type declarations."

I'm fairly certain I'm using the correct path. This is my code for App.tsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import img from "./img/image1.jpg";

 type AppState = {
   start: String,
   end: String
 }

/** Displays the UI of the Polls application. */
export class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {start: "", end: ""};
  }

  render = (): JSX.Element => {
    return <div>
      <h1>Start:</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.dummy_method}></input>
      <h1>End:</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.dummy_method}></input>
      <img src={img} alt={"map"}/>
    </div>;
  };

  dummy_method = () => {
  };
}
```

[image: Files]